# OnItemLongClickListener only deletes SD card file once, then no more

Tags: android, file-io, arraylist, android-sdcard, onitemlongclicklistener

I have an `ArrayList<>` in a `ListView`, so I need an adapter. The list items are saved to file in another activity, and load from my SD card once my `CuteCollection.java` activity runs. I put an `OnItemLongClickListener` on each list item, so that when I click it, the item is not only removed from the list (the adapter), but also the SD card. However, I need to NOT have the full file name, when displaying the title in my `ListView`, so I used `substring` to take off the file extension, which works well. But then a new problem developed... my click listener wouldn't delete the file from my SD card (since it needs the full file name with extension to know which one to delete). To work around that, I used the title of the file, and through `StringBuilder`, added the `.txt` extension back onto the string. But now it will only delete one item from file, but no more. Before I messed with removing the extension, it worked fine. I could delete any list item, by long-clicking it and pressing ok.

Anyone know why it only works once, then doesn't delete anymore? It will remove any item from the list (the adapter), but when I rerun the activity, the old ones load again (except the first one I deleted). This tells me the SD card only had one deleted from it. I need to be able to delete as many as I want. Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I logged both `singleFile` and `sb.toString()` and it looks like the `sb.toString()` has the first long-click file name on the 2nd long-click as well. The `singleFile` file name has 2 unique file names for both clicks, as it should, since there were currently 2 files in the list.

**Before click:**

```
Value of singleFile is: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/CuteWords/Poem_40.txt
Value of singleFile is: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/CuteWords/Poem_89.txt
```

**1st click:**

```
Value of sb.toString() is: Poem_89.txt
```

**2nd click:**

```
Value of sb.toString() is: Poem_89.txt
```

My fragment below:

**TextTab.java** This is a single tab in my **CuteCollection.java** activity.

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class TextTab extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<PoemListItem> poems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListViewPoemAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    String[] allSDCardFiles = null;
    StringBuilder text;
    PoemListItem wordsFromFile;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_tab, container, false);
        adapter = new ListViewPoemAdapter(getActivity(), poems);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // read contents of SD card
        loadSDCard();

        // add the default icon/lines remaining to ArrayList, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - allSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
            PoemListItem sampleItem = new PoemListItem(" ", " ");
            adapter.add(sampleItem);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            i++;
        }


        setupListViewListener();

        return v;

    }

    private void loadSDCard(){
        // gets directory CuteWords from sd card
        File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cuteWordsDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CuteWords");
        // lists all files in CuteWords, loads in Files[] array
        File[] files = cuteWordsDir.listFiles();


        for (File singleFile : files) {
            //Read text from file, put each line into StringBuilder
            text = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(singleFile));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');

                    // get full file name with ext. and text in file
                    wordsFromFile = new PoemListItem(singleFile.getName(), text.toString());

                    // get only name from title (not file extension)
                    String withExt = wordsFromFile.getTitle();
                    String justTitle = withExt.substring(0, withExt.length() - 4);
                    wordsFromFile.setTitle(justTitle);

                    adapter.add(wordsFromFile);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // get number of files in CuteWords directory
        allSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];
    }


    // so you can edit any of the list items
    private void setupListViewListener() {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                        View item, int pos, long id){


            }
        });

        // to delete an item
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                           final int pos, long id) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Delete")
                        .setMessage("Delete these cute words?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // delete from adapter
                                poems.remove(pos);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                // add extension back on file name
                                sb.append(wordsFromFile.getTitle() + ".txt");
                                // get file name then delete it
                                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                        "/Documents/CuteWords/" + sb.toString());
                                file.delete();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // do nothing

                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
     return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you log the filename on first click and second click and post it here

Comment: Which one, `wordsFromFile.getTitle` or `singleFile`?

Comment: Okay, I did both and the file name on the listener had the same value both times. But why?

Comment: are you sure your values are always different for different position you click on

Comment: Yes, they are. I tried adding 4 items to my list and long-clicking them all to delete, and all 4 had the same file value, which was the 1st one I deleted. What's even weirder, is the more I deleted, the value had multiple files repeated on 1 click. `D/TAG﹕ Value of sb is: Poem_75.txtPoem_75.txtPoem_75.txtPoem_75.txt` Actually that makes sense, it must be added that file name, not replacing it. I probably need to delete the `StringBuilder` at the start of each click.

Comment: you can try it and let me know

Comment: Okay, that got rid of the repeated values in `sb`, but it still only deletes one, it always reloads all the other list items when I kill the activity and return. I wonder if it has something to do with the instantiation of `sb`.

Comment: i think wordsFromFile.getTitle() in your sb is giving you repeated values

Comment: No, I think it was the `sb` never changing from click to click. It just kept adding to itself. But that's not a problem anymore, it's just that the value is always the same file, even though I click on a new list item. It shouldn't be the same. :/

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. When I put my `AlertDialog` inside of my long-click listener, I forgot, I had to change my `int pos` to `final int pos`, otherwise it gave a red error. And if you have any variable that is final, its value cannot be changed. I just need to figure a way around that, which is hard. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figure it out. It only deletes once because I did not refresh the writing to file again, after each delete. So, in my case, I needed to run my `loadSDCard()` method immediately after deleting the file. I added the method call at the end of the `AlertDialog` box, right after `file.delete()`. So it had nothing to do with the `pos` variable being final. Basically, you write to file the delete, so you have a new list. Otherwise it thinks your old list is in place and does not change positions. Rewriting actually re-creates the list.

```
// to delete an item
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                                        final int pos, long id) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Delete")
                        .setMessage("Delete these cute words?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // delete from ArrayList first
                                poems.remove(pos);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                // get file name then delete it
                                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                        "/Documents/CuteWords/" + wordsFromFile.getTitle());
                                file.delete();
                                // after each item delete, must refresh load so can delete again
                                loadSDCard();

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                // do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```